# Imagem não aparece react native

Tags: api, react-native, react-hooks, image, expo

Estou com um projeto e nele eu faço upload de imagem com expresse + multer no backend, durante o projeto tem uma parte que mostra essa foto, porem ela não aparece, apenas fica um espaço em branco onde ela deveria estar.

na pagina em questão eu chamo a api pra ela me retornar dados e no meio desses dados vem o caminho da imagem, em seguida guardo esses dados em uma variável useState, crio um flatlist e alimento ele com essa variável, esse flatlist lista postagens, como um instagram, com algumas informações e uma imagem, porém algumas das postagem podem n ter foto então faço um comparação para ver se tem imagem na postagem e so se tiver eu tento mostrar a sua imagem

**Chamando a api e guardando os dados em uma variável**

```
...
Axios.get(apiPath+'/api/showPost').then((response) => {
setPostList(response.data); // colocar o json q o backend devolveu na variável postList
```

**Flatlist**

```
<FlatList
      data={postList}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          return(
            
            
            
            <View style={styles.postagemRed}>
              
                <View style={styles.postCima}>
                  

                  <Text style={styles.iconPost}></Text>
                  <View style={styles.separador}>
                    <View style={styles.nomeDate}>
                      <Text style={styles.postText}>{item.nome}</Text>
                      <Text style={[styles.postText, styles.dateText]}>
                        { // tratamento da variável de data
                          item.data.substring(8,10)+'/'+ // dia
                          item.data.substring(5,7) +'/'+ // mes
                          item.data.substring(0,4)       // ano
                        }   
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={[styles.postText, styles.cargoText]} >{item.identificacao}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
              
                
                
                
                {item.path &&

                    //por algum motivo a imagem não aparece  // assim funciona source={require("../../img/postagemPhoto/postagemPicture1633288577901.jpg")}
                    <View>
                      
                    
                    <Text style={styles.tituloText}>{item.path}</Text>
                    <Image style={styles.imagePost}  source={{uri : item.path}} />
                    </View>
                  }
                  
                  
                  


                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.postBaixo}
                underlayColor='#FFFFFF00'
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('OpenPost', {idPost : item.id })}>
                  <View>


                    <Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode={'tail'} style={styles.tituloText}>{item.titulo}</Text>
                    <Text style={[styles.tituloText, styles.temaTexto]} >{item.tema}</Text>
                  
    
                    <View style={styles.corpoPost}>
                      <Text numberOfLines={3} ellipsizeMode={'tail'} style={styles.postTexto}>
                      {item.texto}
                      </Text>
                    </View>              
                  </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
              

          </View>


          );
        }}
        />
```

**Comparação se a postagem tem foto e tentando mostrar a foto**

```
{item.path &&

                //por algum motivo a imagem não aparece  // assim funciona source={require("../../img/postagemPhoto/postagemPicture1633288577901.jpg")}
                <View>


                <Text style={styles.tituloText}>{item.path}</Text>  //isso é pra ver se o caminho ta chegando certo
                <Image style={styles.imagePost}  source={{uri : item.path}} />
                </View>
              }
```

o caminho esta chegando certo e se eu colocar ele direto ele funciona, porem como vão ficar adicionando postagem durante o uso fica inviável colocar cada foto diretamente
OBS: todo o código esta apenas na minha maquina e uso expo no meu próprio celular para "testar" o app

[image: print do resultado do código no expo no meu celular:]

OBS²: a foto deveria aparecer entre o caminho q esta como texto e o porfavor

Answer (score -1):

Tente usando `require` ao invés de `{uri:}`:

```
<Image style={styles.imagePost}  source={require(item.path)} />
<Image style={styles.imagePost}  source={require(item.path)} />
```

`require` funciona melhor para imagens que estão em local.

Para mais informações sobre `<Image />`, acesse a [documentação](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).